# Move all changes/commits from current branch to a different branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I was modifying some code in a team repo and mistakenly made all my changes in the 'master' branch when I should have been working in the 'Development' branch. I committed my changes before I realized this, but I'm not able to push changes directly to master.

So I need to move all my commits to Development, push them, and then discard all the changes on master.

Is there a straightforward way of doing this? I was thinking 'rebase Master into Development' but I'm not 100% sure about that. I'm using VS and the built-in git GUI tools.

Comment: A branch is just a pointer to a blob. So, if you want `Development` to point to the same blob that `master` currently points to, then you will need to merge `Development` into `master`. Let me know if you have any questions about this part.

Comment: To make `master` point to an older blob, you'll need to get the short hash of whichever older blob you plan on reverting `master` back to. Once you get that, make sure you are sitting on `master`, then **hard reset** to that blob. If you have any more questions, feel free to reply to this comment and I'm more than happy to answer.

Answer (score -1):

Okay after comparing a lot of different methods this is what wound up working perfectly for my situation:

1. Checkout/switch to Development (the branch where I want my commits)
2. In console: "git cherry-pick commit1 commit2 commit3" - where commit1 is the oldest (first) commit that I want and commit3 is the newest
3. Checkout/switch back to master
4. Reset --hard to the last commit that you want to *keep*, discards all changes

Comment: Could also have used `git rebase --onto`.

Comment: It seems you didn't fully comprehend my comments under your question. There was not really a need for cherry picking in your situation. You could have simply looked at the git tree and moved the branch to the correct blob. This just added unnecessary complexity. I'm glad you got the result you wanted, but you should really try to learn what a branch is for future situations.

Comment: You mentioned in the first part that I would have to merge  Development into Master, but as I said in the post I'm not able to push any changes or merge with master (team permission thing). sorry if I'm still misunderstanding something there